# Simplifying database relationships design

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this little Laravel project where members can pay to attend to a class, pay insurance, event, or pay to pass a special type of exams.

So I have 5 tables `members`, `classes`, `insurance`, `events` and `exams`, and I need to add the `payments` table so I can track members payments for each one of those tables.

So for the moment the `payments` table is going to be like this :

```
id      date            amount      member_id   class_id    insurance_id    event_id    exam_id
1       2019-01-01      150         2           1           NULL            NULL        NULL
2       2019-01-01      250         11          NULL        14              NULL        NULL
3       2019-01-01      220         15          NULL        NULL            6           NULL
4       2019-01-01      350         32          NULL        NULL            NULL        8
```

Is there a better way to this without having :
`class_id, insurance_id, event_id, exam_id` fields in the payments table, because this is going to make the relationship more complexe I guess, and to also maybe simply DB queries using Laravel as a PHP Framework.

Comment: Actually i think this is the best way. The relations wont really be that complicated and the query will be much easier since there wont be any pivots or other things to worry about

Comment: However you can simplify it a bit if for example the exam model contains class_id. In that case you can get the class_id from the exam instead of listing it here. And so on

Comment: I'd suggest a payment *linking*-table per type. E.g. keep payments as is, but remove `class_id`, `insurance_id`, `event_id` and `exam_id`. Create extra tables for each. E.g. `exam_payments` with: `payment_id, exam_id` and similar.

Comment: I have a Many To Many relationship table between `exams` & `members` which is `exam_member` table, and having these columns (`member_id`, `exam_id`, `transaction_id`) I guess that would do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to go is a one to many polymorphic relationship.

#### Database/migrations setup

To do so you would need:

- A `members` table to hold members data.
- One table for each type of *payable entity* in your system (`classes`, `insurance`, `events` and `exams`)
- A `payments` table structured with the following migration:

```php
Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    // Payment related fields like date and amount

    $table->unsignedInteger('member_id');
    // Assuming id is the primary key on the members table
    $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');

    // This one will create two fields:
    //  - payable_type
    //  - payable_id
    $table->morphs('payable');
});
```

This way each record would hold the member that made the payment (through `member_id`) and the paid entity (through `payable_type` and `payable_id`).

#### Eloquent Models Relationships

You then have to setup morphing relationships on your payment model like:

```php
// app\Payment.php

class Payment extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function payable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
    }
}
```

Your member model as:

```php
// app\Member.php

class Member extends Model
{
    // ...    
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
}
```

And for each payable entity:

```php
// app\Insurance.php

class Insurance extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Payment::class, 'payable');
    }
}
```

```php
// app\Event.php

class Event extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Payment::class, 'payable');
    }
}
```

```php
// app\Exam.php

class Exam extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Payment::class, 'payable');
    }
}
```

```php
// app\Course.php

// I renamed "Class" payable entity to "Course"
// as "class" is a reserved keyword in PHP and
// you can't give a class the name "Class".
class Course extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Payment::class, 'payable');
    }
}
```

#### Usage

If you would need to retrive all the payments (of different types) made by a user you would just have to query the member model like that:

```php
$member = Member::with('payments.payable')->first();
dd($member->payments);
```

If you set up model relations accordingly, Laravel will resolve the different correct Eloquent model instances based on the payable_type and payable_id of each record with a matching member_id.

As a result, `$member->payments` will be a collection of instances of Payment each with a relationship to one of `Insurance`, `Exam`, `Course` and `Event` classes (based on the payable_type stored in database).

For reference and a more detailed usage, you could look at the official Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Comment: Thanks ! this was really helpful

Comment: How do you suggest I get the list of courses payments of a member ? does this seem ok `        $member->whereHas('payable', function($query) { $query->where('payments.payable_type', "App\\Course"); })->get();
`

Comment: Try with $member->payments()->where('payable_type', Course::class)->get().

Calling the payments relationship as a method will get you the query builder instance on that relationship and you can further filter it based on your needs, then call ->get() to actually query the db and get results back

Answer (score 1):

Without using all ids in one table use transaction table and use that transaction_id in all those tables.

Table transaction => id, payment_data, created_at, created_by etc

Table event => id, name, transaction_id etc

Comment: How would this allow multiple users to pay for the same event?

Comment: I have a many to many relationship between `members` & `events` through the relation table `event_member`, this is the one I'll add `transaction_id` to.